# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. unable to get the permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I am making a database in sql server and it shows an error that `"CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'"`
I am using the administrator log in itself.
What i need to do?
Please suggest a fix!

[image: This is the screenshot and the error message i used to get when i create a database in sql server 2008]

Comment: Do you use the Windows admin login or the SQL Server admin? If the former, it doesn't neccessarily mean that the Windows admin is a SQL Server admin automatically. Can you try it using the sa account?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The user must be a member of `dbcreator` server role for user to have enough permissions to create a database.

You can execute the following statement to make a user member of `dbcreator` server role.

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'Shubhankar', @rolename = N'dbcreator'
GO
```

Or you Can/Should use

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE  [dbcreator]  ADD MEMBER [Shubhankar];
GO
```

Members of `sysadmin` role are by default members of `dbcreator` server role therefore they can create databases too.

Comment: Where do I enter that using SQL Server 2022?

Answer (score 5):

All the above points are clear but there is one which is missing. I struggled to find the solution to this problem and finally got it after long research.

To get permission to create database in your local account follow the below given steps.

Step 1: Disconnect from your local account.

Step 2: Again Connect to Server with **Login : sa** and **Password : pwd**(pwd given to your local login).

Step 3: **Object Explorer -> Security -> Logins -> Right click on your server name -> Properties -> Server Roles -> sysadmin -> OK**

Step 4: Disconnect and connect to your local login and create database.

Successfully created the database  :D ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Azure, the command is a little different:

```
ALTER ROLE [dbmanager] ADD MEMBER [Shubhankar];
```

Answer (score 1):

To create database you need **sysadmin** **role permission** for the user. Go to **Database-> Security -> Logins**  section in **object explorer** and edit the **properties** of the user that you want to have create permission. In the **Server Roles** section you can find **sysadmin**. Tick it and save the user. Now you will have access to create database.

For Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/76fc84f9-437c-4e71-ba3d-3c9ae794a7c4/sql-express-2008-r2-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master?forum=sqlexpress

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, I noticed I was connected using **Windows Authentication**. I then disconnected and used **SQL Server Authentication**. It started good.